# How to solve import CNTK library?

Tags: python, cntk

I have problem with linking CNTK library with Anaconda.

My PYTHONPATH: `c:\repos\cntk\bindings\python;%PYTHONPATH%`

My CNTK_PY_35: `C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35`

And I have error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/szymo/PycharmProjects/ImageClassification/Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cntk
  File "c:\repos\cntk\bindings\python\cntk\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .core import *
  File "c:\repos\cntk\bindings\python\cntk\core.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import cntk_py
ImportError: cannot import name 'cntk_py'
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Best

Comment: Is cntk_py.py in the same folder as core.py (c:\repos\cntk\bindings\python\cntk\)? Are you building the bindings by yourself or using a binary installation or wheel file?

Answer (score 0):

As Nikos points, this is very likely due to mixing up of binary installation with the toolkit being built from the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add something like `--with-py36-path=/opt/anaconda/envs/cntk-py36` to your `./configure` command options before building `CNTK`. Please note that you may need to modify the path and Python version according to your setting. The above option is for `Arch Linux` with `Python 3.6` (`Anaconda`).